# Блокировка вращения персонажа по локальной оси

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform, rotation

Мобильная игра про космос, персонаж поворачивается влево-вправо с помощью джойстика.
Когда дело происходит на земле, то всё нормально, но в небе он вращается на все 360 градусов.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы персонаж вращался, но не до конца.

Например:

- поворачиваешь налево
- сама фигура поворачивается максимум на 30 градусов
- в целом поворот выполняется на все 360 градусов.

Наверноe, нужно использовать `Mathf.Clamp`, но я не знаю как

Мой код:

```
float x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
float y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    rigidBody.AddForce (transform.up * flySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (Time.deltaTime * -y * rotateSpeed,Time.deltaTime * x * rotateSpeed,0f));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял формулировку задачи, то снизу написал, вроде как, рабочий код скрипта для объекта, который не может поворачиваться больше, чем на 30 градусов влево, и на 30 градусов вправо. Из-за того, что в Unity `Transform.rotation` варьируется от 0 до 1-го мы юзаем `transform.localRotation.eulerAngles`. И ещё один момент: получается, что когда наш объект находится в изначальном положении (т.е. угол поворота по Z = 0), то есть 2 варианта отклонения - либо 30 влево, либо 330 вправо. Т.е. не -30. И из-за этого больше получилось условий, чем могло бы быть при -30.

```
private const float Speed = 0.1f;
private const float FlySpeed = 0.1f;
private const float RotateSpeed = 5f;
private const float MaxRotation = 30f;
private const float MinRotaion = 360f - MaxRotation;

Rigidbody rigidBody;

private void Start()
{
    rigidBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    //получаем угол поворота по Z
    float rotationZ = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z;

    float x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * FlySpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if ((x > 0 && rotationZ + (RotateSpeed * x) < MaxRotation) || rotationZ + (RotateSpeed * x) > MinRotaion || (x < 0 && (rotationZ + (RotateSpeed * x) < MinRotaion) && (rotationZ + (RotateSpeed * x) > MinRotaion) || (rotationZ + (RotateSpeed * x) < 30)))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, RotateSpeed * x));
    }
}
```